# React Context with TypeScript - Type not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-typescript

I'm implementing Context into my project, which so far looks like this:

```
import {
    ReactNode,
    createContext,
    useState,
    Dispatch,
    SetStateAction,
} from 'react';

export type Admin = {
    admin: boolean;
};

export interface AdminContextInterface {
    admin: boolean;
    setAdmin: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Admin>>;
}

const defaultState = {
    admin: false,
    setAdmin: (admin: Admin) => {},
} as AdminContextInterface;

export const AdminContext = createContext(defaultState);

export type AdminContextProviderProps = {
    children: ReactNode;
};

export const AdminContextProvider = ({
    children,
}: AdminContextProviderProps) => {
    const [admin, setAdmin] = useState<Admin>({ admin: false });
    return (
        <AdminContext.Provider value={{ admin, setAdmin }}>
            {children}
        </AdminContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Unfortunately I have an error related to admin in `<AdminContext.Provider value={{ admin, setAdmin }}>`
The error says :
Type 'Admin' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
The expected type comes from property 'admin' which is declared here on type 'AdminContextInterface'

Any idea where is the issue comming from?

Comment: in your `AdminContextInterface ` you defined prop `admin` as a boolean. but in the provider, you pass in `admin` from the state with the determined type `Admin` aka an object `{ admin: false }`. That is the issue of mismatched types.

Comment: either change your state to store a plain boolean and `setAdmin` to accept a boolean or change the `admin` prop in the `AdminContextInterface` to accept the `Admin` type instead of a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch in the type of "admin" between the AdminContext and the useState.
[image]

Here is the corrected code.

```
import {
  ReactNode,
  createContext,
  useState,
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
} from 'react';

export interface AdminContextInterface {
  admin: boolean;
  setAdmin: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const defaultState = {
  admin: false,
  setAdmin: (admin: boolean) => {},
} as AdminContextInterface;

export const AdminContext = createContext(defaultState);

export type AdminContextProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

export const AdminContextProvider = ({
  children,
}: AdminContextProviderProps) => {
  const [admin, setAdmin] = useState<boolean>(false);
  return (
    <AdminContext.Provider value={{ admin, setAdmin }}>
      {children}
    </AdminContext.Provider>
  );
};
```